# How result List with 3 columns STREAM

Tags: java, arraylist, stream, java-stream

Making Java 8 Stream lets you create nation list with Higher Quantity of each product.

Before ( original):

**China Mouse 4**

**Brazil Mouse 3**

**Brazil Keyboard 3**

**France Keyboard 2**

After ( result ) :

**China Mouse 4**

**Brazil Keyboard 3**

It is possible to make Stream?

Comment: Not sure what you need here. May be code snippet would help.

Comment: unless you provide your attempts, it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
      productList.add(new Product("China","Mouse",4));
      productList.add(new Product("Brazil","Mouse",3));
      productList.add(new Product("Brazil","Keyboard",3));
      productList.add(new Product("France","Keyboard",2));

      productList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getProductName,Product::getQuantity,(q1,q2)->q1<q2?q2:q1));
```

With Product class :

```
class Product {
    private String productName;
    private String nation;
    private int quantity;

    public Product(String nation, String productName, int quantity) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.nation = nation;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```